# URL like tree with 2 models CBV

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have 3 models:

1. dish(fk dishclass)
2. dishtype(fk dishtype)
3. dishclass

Dishclass can be without dishtype.
Example:

```
1)obj1 dishtype = Margarita; dishclass = Pizza
2)obj2 dishtype = Alfonso; dishclass = Pizza
3)obj3 dishtype = Burger; dishclass = none
```

Then i make ListView with object on url /dish/:
Pizza(if obj have dishclass, show only dishclass) 
Burger

I want this logic:

if i click to `Pizza` -> `/dish/pizza/` and have objects `Margarita` and `Alfonso`-> clik to name of pizza and go to `/dish/pizza/margarita` etc.

if i click to `Burger` -> `/dish/burger/`

Now my code is working only like this: `/dish/burger/` and `/dishclass/pizza`

I try this code:

**Models**

```
class DishClass(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      slug = models.SlugField()

      def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dishclass_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

class DishType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    dishclass = models.ForeignKey(DishClass, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dish_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Dish(models.Model):
    dishtype = models.ForeignKey(DishType)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

**Views**

```
class DishListView(ListView):
    model = Dish
    template_name = 'dish.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(DishListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    alltypes = DishType.objects.all()
    all_dish = Dish.objects.all()
    dict = {}
    k = 0
    for category in alltypes:
        for dishes in all_dish:
            if dishes.dish.dishtype.name == category.name:
                k=k+1
        if category.dishclass:
            if category.dishclass in dict:
                dict[category.dishclass] += k
            else:
                dict[category.dishclass] = k
            k = 0
        else:
            dict[category] = k
            k = 0
    context['dict'] = sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return context


class DishTypeView(TemplateView):

template_name = 'dish_type.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['dish_obj_by_type'] = Dish.objects.filter(dishtype__slug=DishType.objects.get(slug=kwargs['dish_type_slug']).slug)
    return context


class DishClassView(TemplateView):

template_name = 'dish_class.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # context['if_dishclass_is_none'] = Dish.objects.filter(dishtype__slug=DishType.objects.get(slug=kwargs['dish_class_slug']).slug)
    context['dish_type'] = DishType.objects.filter(dishclass__slug=DishClass.objects.get(slug=kwargs['dish_class_slug']).slug)
return context
```

**URLS**

```
url(r'^dish/$', DishListView.as_view(), name='dish'),
url(r'^dish/(?P<dish_class_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<dish_type_slug>[\w-]+)/$', DishTypeView.as_view(), name='dish_type'),
url(r'^dish/(?P<dish_class_slug>[\w-]+)/$', DishClassView.as_view(), name='dish_class')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a generic view rather than a `DetailView` and then collect together the objects you want based on the `kwargs` provided;

```
url(
    r'^dish/(?P<dish_class_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<dish_type_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 
    DishTypeView.as_view(), name='dish_type'
),
url(
    r'^dish/(?P<dish_class_slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    DishClassView.as_view(), name='dish_class'
),
```

View example;

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import TemplateView

from .models import DishClass, DishType


class DishTypeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'dish_type.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['dish_class'] = DishClass.objects.get(slug=kwargs['dish_class_slug'])
        context['dish_type'] = DishType.objects.get(slug=kwargs['dish_type_slug'])
        return context
```

Comment: Its not working for mе in DishClassView.
1)obj1 dishtype = Alfonso; dishclass = Pizza
2)obj2 dishtype = Burger; dishclass = none
'
context['dish_class'] = DishClass.objects.get(slug=kwargs['dish_class_slug'])
'
I want /dish/burger/ and /dish/pizza/, but i have error, because burger kwargs['dish_class_slug'] its dishtype.slug

What i need to do?

Comment: @Anton I'm not really understanding what the issue is. Update your question to include the view & the full error stacktrace.

Comment: markwalker_ i update urls and views
 problem in DishClassView(error matching query does not exist)
 i want this logic:
 if object have dishclass->i want types;
 if object dishclass=none->i want list of dish, filter by dishtype